# Skip IF folder name contains "zyx"

Tags: batch-file

The code below works well, it finds the latest folder created and adds "- ESP" at the end of it e.g. Folder `TEST123` to `TEST123 - ESP`.

However if by chance the script is executed again for whatever reason, the folder looks like this `TEST123 - ESP -ESP`.

The idea would be to check the latest folder has `ESP` in its name.

I assume that an IF / ELSE is needed but I am not sure if I need to use a find command.

```
FOR /F "delims=\" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
    SET a=%%i
    GOTO :found
)
echo No subfolder found
goto :eof
:found
```

Should the IF / ELSE be here?

```
echo Most recent subfolder: "%a%"
cd %a%
for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "%%~na-%a%%%~xa"
cd ..\
ren "%a%" "%a% - ESP"
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit :

```
FOR /F "delims=\" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
    SET a=%%i
    GOTO :found
)
echo No subfolder found
goto :eof

:found
echo Most recent subfolder: "%a%"
if  /i "%a:~-3%"=="ESP" goto:next
cd %a%
for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "%%~na-%a%%%~xa"
cd ..\
ren "%a%" "%a% - ESP"
pause
exit /b

:next
echo done
```

This will check for the 3 last char of your Folder.

Comment: Hello, I would only want to check the last folder created, all the other folder would be irrelevant.

Comment: I appreciate the support, however it did not rename the folder with - ESP nor its content, instead is renamed the script file. I think something is a little off.

Comment: I forget the cd %a% try again